# Почему вывод данных не соответствует условию?

Tags: php, laravel

> У меня должны выходить данные по условию(с 22-12-2020 по 29-12-2020)
>   ну у меня выходят пользователи только с первой датой (22-12-2020)

***контроллер***

```
  public  function seach(Request $request){
        $data_ot = $request->input('data_ots');
        $data_do = $request->input('data_dos');
        if($data_ot==null&&$data_do==null){
            return redirect('statisk');
        }
        $stata = Statistik::wherebetween('date_chek',[$data_ot,$data_do])->get();
        return view('admin.pages.statistik', compact('stata'));
    }
```

> данные приходят верные но появляются пользователи только с ($data_ot)

Comment: проверьте входные данные, проверьте сам генерируемый запрос, проверьте наличие соответсвующих данных в БД. Возможно, в проверке на `Null` вам таки нужно проверять `||` а не `&&`

Comment: данные в бд сходятся

Comment: +ошибка; правильный метод `whereBetween()` (camelCase)